# How are Durbin-Watson critical values calculated?

Tags: durbin-watson-test

I am wondering how Durbin-Watson critical values (i.e. dL and du) are calculated.

See the Durbin-Watson Significance table

- https://www3.nd.edu/~wevans1/econ30331/Durbin_Watson_tables.pdf
- https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/regression/supporting-topics/model-assumptions/test-for-autocorrelation-by-using-the-durbin-watson-statistic/

However, I failed to find any formula / code regarding how the table is computed for a given significance.  Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: It's very complicated. Some dude made it work 70 years ago, and no ever bothered to check it ever since. We all just use it.

Comment: See Turner, Paul. "Critical values for the Durbin-Watson test in large samples." Applied Economics Letters 27.18 (2020): 1495-1499.  There is no code, but the paper provided a site which you can query some values.  You can then linearly extrapolate the rest.